# Why isn't Task.WhenAll waiting until completion?

Tags: c#, linq, async-await, task, task-parallel-library

I'm running into an issue here and you might know the answer: I just couldn't figure it out still.

I'm creating a seed for a simple scenario here: adding likes to a given post.
The method signature is:

```
async Task GeneratePostLike(string postId, string userId, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default) {
    return await postLikeService.AddUserLikeToPost(
      new PostLikeInput { PostId = postId, UserId = userId },
      cancellationToken
    );
}
```

I want to randomly generate likes to a post. I'm using random and other mechanisms to get a random number for doing such.

When I use an old for-loop block, it executes the way I want. This is the instructions I'm using:

```
var numberOfLikesForPost = random.Next(1, 100);
var randomUsersForLikes = await userService.GetRandomUsers(numberOfLikesForPost);

for (var likeIndex = 0; likeIndex < numberOfLikesForPost; likeIndex++)
{
  var randomUserId = randomUsersForLikes.PickRandom().Id;
  await GeneratePostLike(post.Id!, randomUserId, cancellationToken);
}
```

[image]

However, when I try to use `Task.WhenAll`, it simply executes one or two iterations and carries on. Seems like it's behaving like fire-and-forget of some sort. The following code represents what I'm doing with `Task.WhenAll` block:

```
var numberOfLikesForPost = random.Next(1, 100);
var randomUsersForLikes = await userService.GetRandomUsers(numberOfLikesForPost);

var generatePostLikeTasks = Enumerable.Repeat(
  GeneratePostLike(
    post.Id!,
    randomUsersForLikes.PickRandom().Id,
    cancellationToken
  ),
  numberOfLikesForPost
);

await Task.WhenAll(generatePostLikeTasks);
```

[image]

Do you have any suggestions of what can I add in order to make my `Task.WhenAll` block properly await execution of all tasks before carrying on?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others to provide an answer faster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var generatePostLikeTasks = Enumerable.Repeat(
  GeneratePostLike(
    post.Id!,
    randomUsersForLikes.PickRandom().Id,
    cancellationToken
  ),
  numberOfLikesForPost
);
```

This will not create `numberOfLikesForPost` number of Tasks but will just repeat the same Task instance for `numberOfLikesForPost` times.

You should be able to change this to something like below. Haven't tested it yet because I don't have access to an IDE at the moment.

```
var generatePostLikeTasks = Enumerable.Repeat(
  () => GeneratePostLike(
    post.Id!,
    randomUsersForLikes.PickRandom().Id,
    cancellationToken
  ),
  numberOfLikesForPost
).Select(f => f());
```

Comment: Bingo! That was it :) thanks a bunch, was not spotting that the function was just not being randomized properly!!

Comment: Instead of `Enumerable.Repeat+Select`, `Enumerable.Range+Select` should be simpler and less convoluted.